# Solr: Avoid spell check on numbers within the string field

Tags: search

I've 2 fields title and description in apache solr, both are the text_general field type contains string as well as numbers and I applied the spell check on both field by createing single copy field for both title and description. and applied spellcheck on that field.

Now, I want to avoid the spell check on numbers present in title and description but other string should have the spell check.

how can i implement this solution. help appreciated.

Comment: Is this question connected to Drupal in some way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.